# Extract number from string with regex in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy, extract

I have the following type of strings with numbers within:

```
(12  -   17)
(4.5  - 5.5)
(4    -  10)
```

My code which works for the first two examples is like this:

```
def numbers=range=~/\d{1,3}.?\d{1,2}?/
```

where the result for numbers is :

```
[12,17]
[4.5,5.5]
```

but for the last is only 
`[10]` it does not get the `4`.

Does anyone see where I am wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your regex requires at least 2 integer digits on end. Look: `\d{1,3}` matches 1 to 3 digits, `.?` matches any character but a newline 1 or 0 times (optional) and `\d{1,2}?` matches 1 or 2 digits (the `{1,2}?` is a *lazy* version of a limiting quantifier meaning it will match as few digits as possible to return a valid match).

Use

```
/\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM7nS3/1).

**Explanation**:

- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - 1 or 0 sequences (due to `?`) of:

  - `\.` - a literal period
  - `\d{1,2}` - 2 or 1 digits (this is a *greedy* version of the limiting quantifier).

Here is a [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/z48jzq):

```
def x = "(12  -   17)(4.5  - 5.5)(4    -  10)"
def res = x.findAll(/\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?/)
println res
```

Output: `[12, 17, 4.5, 5.5, 4, 10]`